# Show ExpansionComponent programmatically

Tags: smartgwt

Is it possible to trigger the "show ExpansionComponent event" programmatically?

I have already defined `grid.setCanExpandRecords(true)` and it works as expected but I was wondering myself if the expansion of a certain record can be initiated through any other way then hitting the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
targetListGrid.expandRecord(targetListGrid.getSelectedRecord());
```